# TextFields using decimalKeyboard not scrolling to visible area when moved from a field using the normal keyboard in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

Any idea why `Field 3` and `Field 5` do not get visible when active if the previous field was using the normal keyboard?

In the following code, if you tap on `Field 1` and immediately after you tap on `Field 3` or `Field 5`, they will not be visible; they get hidden by the keyboard.

Please note that `Field 3` and `Field 5` use the `decimalPad` keyboard while the rest of the fields use the standard keyboard.

```
  struct TextFieldScrollingIssue: View {
    @State private var testInput:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form {
                TextField("Field 1", text:$testInput)
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Section(header: Text("Section 1: ")) {
                    TextField("Field 2", text:$testInput)
                    TextField("Field 3", text:$testInput)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Section 2: ")) {
                    TextField("Field 4", text:$testInput)
                    TextField("Field 5", text:$testInput)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see the problem on simulators. On a couple of test devices, I can't recreate the problem. (ipad/16.1/landscape and iphone 12 pro max/ 16.2/portrait)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test. I see the same issue in the simulator and in multiple devices, iPhone XS iOS16.1.2 and iPhone 13 iOS15.3.

Comment: This seems like a bug that's worth filing with Apple, and it's not the first one I've seen with regards to the builtin keyboard scrolling. In UIKit we used to complain about writing boilerplate code to deal with the keyboard popping up and scrolling views, so in SwiftUI we get it for free but with bugs. My suggestion, build it in UIKit and live to fight another day.

Comment: The issue I saw with keyboard scrolling was when trying to show a sheet with a text field already in focus. In UIKit, the sheet will animate in together with the keyboard, but in SwiftUI, the sheet will animate fully, and then the keyboard will animate. It's a pretty terrible UX.

Comment: @RonSrebro - Just to be clear, are you suggesting creating the `TextFields` in `UIKit`? Thank you for your input.

Comment: I'm suggesting creating the entire view in UIKit where you can have full control of how to scroll your view in response to the keyboard showing up. You'll find dozens of samples on how to make that work. Here's one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present-on-starting/1127025#1127025
If you're really committed to swiftUI, I would explore removing the Form view as I think that is probably where the problem is and implementing your own scrolling similar to @Yrb's answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the scrolling mechanism is confused because you used the same variable for all of the `TextFields`. Obviously, in production, you would never have this scenario. The fix is simple, use different variables:

```
struct TextFieldScrollingIssue: View {
    @FocusState var isFocused: String?
    @State private var testInput:String = ""
    @State private var decimalInput:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollViewReader { scroll in
                Form {
                    TextField("Field 1", text:$testInput)
                        .id("Field 1")
                        .focused($isFocused, equals: "Field 1")
                    Text(isFocused?.description ?? "nil")
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Section(header: Text("Section 1: ")) {
                        TextField("Field 2", text:$testInput)
                            .id("Field 2")
                            .focused($isFocused, equals: "Field 2")
                        TextField("Field 3", text:$decimalInput)
                            .id("Field 3")
                            .focused($isFocused, equals: "Field 3")
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Section 2: ")) {
                        TextField("Field 4", text:$testInput)
                            .id("Field 4")
                            .focused($isFocused, equals: "Field 4")
                        TextField("Field 5", text:$decimalInput)
                            .id("Field 5")
                            .focused($isFocused, equals: "Field 5")
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: isFocused) { _ in
                    if let isFocused = isFocused {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            withAnimation {
                                scroll.scrollTo(isFocused)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Based on the comment, I was able to reproduce. Edited code to use a `ScrollviewReader`, `@FocusState` and view ids to correct.

Comment: The variable is definitely not the issue, I'm having this issue in a real application where all variables are different, I also tried it in my original post sample with different variables and I still see the issue. By the way, in order for you to see the issue you need to add the spacers I have in my original post otherwise the keyboard will not cover the fields and it may seem like there is no issue. Thanks.

Comment: I redacted them from my answer with the ellipsis. They are there in my code. It is working with no problem. Xcode 13.3RC, iOS 15.4. What are you seeing this on? Does it have to be a device? I suspect that you do not actually have a minimal reproducible example. What is your data model in your actual app?

Comment: I see the issue in a device or the simulator, the code I'm showing is all my code no data models. Here is what I'm doing. With the code above, I tap on Field 1, at this point Field 4 and Field 5 are not visible since they are covered by the keyboard (this is important otherwise you will not see the issue), right after Field 1 I scroll up and tap on Field 5, here is the issue,  Field 5 goes back to its original position, which was underneath the keyboard. I have tested this in multiple devices and multiple simulators.

Comment: That would have been an important pice of information to put in your initial question. I can confirm that following these steps causes the issue. I would report this as a bug. I will work on trying to come up with a workaround.

Comment: Changed code to correct for the issue brought up in comments. I would file a radar with Apple and put the FB# in comments.

Comment: Please note that what I described in my previous comment was noted in the second paragraph of my original post. Sorry if it was confusing.  Thanks a lot for the updated code. Is there a way to keep track of the radar from Apple? I would like to know when a fix is available.

Comment: By the way, the only issue with your updated code is going from `Field 3` to `Field 4`, field 4 is hidden by the keyboard.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Hi, why was the answer from `Francis F` deleted?